# Problem using 'responds_to_parent' with an iframe and AJAX to upload a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, response

I followed instructions from the "[AJAX file uploads in Rails using attachment_fu and responds_to_parent](http://khamsouk.souvanlasy.com/articles/ajax-file-uploads-in-rails-using-attachment_fu-and-responds_to_parent)" article. In my case I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and Paperclip.

What I made is the following:

---

I have installed the 'respons_to_parent' plugin running this command in the Terminal:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/itkin/respond_to_parent.git
```

After installing, I restart Apache.

---

In my view I have:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :multipart => true, :target => 'upload_frame' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>

<div id="test">Here is a test</div>
<div id="stuff">Here is some stuff</div>
<iframe id='upload_frame' name="upload_frame" style="width:1px;height:1px;border:0px" ></iframe>
```

---

In my controller I have

```
  def action
    respond_to do |format|
      ...
      format.js {
        responds_to_parent do
          render :update do |page|
            page.replace_html :test, "This is the resulting test"
            page << "alert($('stuff').innerHTML)"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

---

Trying to submit the form, all about the file uploading works (Paperclip handle correclty files, ...) and in the log file there aren't errors.

The *only* thing that isn't working is the AJAX part. In the example

```
page.replace_html :test, "This is the resulting test"
page << "alert($('stuff').innerHTML)"
```

don't update the page (BTW: where these should have effect? in the "main view" or in the "iframe view"?). It doesn't work also if I try to delete the 'respons_to_parent' statement or if I put them in the 'action.js.rjs' file.

**Where I am wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I had forgotten to add `:url => users_account_path +. "js"`. So the view become:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => users_account_path +. "js", :html => { :multipart => true, :target => 'upload_frame' }) do |f| %>
```